# How to get "Application Trace" instead of full verbose backtrace in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

In Rails default error page of development environment, you can view three backtraces, 1. Application Trace, 2. Framework Trace and 3. Full Trace.

But how can I get "Application Trace" in Rails controllers. Full Trace (exception.backtrace) is too much for me.
Now I'm doing like this:

```
exception.backtrace.select {|line| line =~ /myappname/i }
```

Is this a correct way? Or are there other cooler ways to get it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I looked up rails sources to see how it is implemented. `ActionSupport` has class `BacktraceCleaner`, which is self describable I guess. Using it Rails adds filters to backtraces: in `ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper` :

```
def application_trace
  clean_backtrace(:silent)
end

def framework_trace
  clean_backtrace(:noise)
end

def full_trace
  clean_backtrace(:all)
end
```

`clean_backtrace` turns out to be calling `clean` method on instance of `BacktraceCleaner` (available for users in `Rails.backtrace_cleaner`),   which, in turn, just applies filters. You can read `rails/active_support/lib/active_support/backtrace_cleaner.rb` to see how it is implemented, I can assure you it's very simple.

Actual filters for application backtrace are defined in `railties/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb`:

```
module Rails
  class BacktraceCleaner < ActiveSupport::BacktraceCleaner
    APP_DIRS_PATTERN = /^\/?(app|config|lib|test)/
    RENDER_TEMPLATE_PATTERN = /:in `_render_template_\w*'/

    def initialize
      super
      add_filter   { |line| line.sub("#{Rails.root}/", '') }
      add_filter   { |line| line.sub(RENDER_TEMPLATE_PATTERN, '') }
      add_filter   { |line| line.sub('./', '/') } # for tests

      add_gem_filters
      add_silencer { |line| line !~ APP_DIRS_PATTERN }
    end

    private
      def add_gem_filters
        gems_paths = (Gem.path | [Gem.default_dir]).map { |p| Regexp.escape(p) }
        return if gems_paths.empty?

        gems_regexp = %r{(#{gems_paths.join('|')})/gems/([^/]+)-([\w.]+)/(.*)}
        add_filter { |line| line.sub(gems_regexp, '\2 (\3) \4') }
      end
  end
end
```

And `add_silencer`, checking for `APP_DIRS_PATTERN = /^\/?(app|config|lib|test)/` tells us that you was pretty much close :) don't be confused by filters: they just cut full path to files.

Having sad that, I suggest you use `Rails.backtrace_cleaner` for the job. It is cooler way that you are looking for

Comment: lobanovadik, yes this is it! I just got what I needed in a line of code!
`Rails.backtrace_cleaner.clean(exception.backtrace)`
And I have also noticed there is a `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb` by default. Maybe I should use this, but anyway thanks a lot!